# Apple Mach-O linker error: no such file or directory: 'SystemConfiguration'

Tags: linker-errors

I am using cocoa pods in my project.When i create a pod file in project and adding google Maps, its giving an error- Apple Mach-O linker error: no such file or directory: 'SystemConfiguration'. I have tried to get rid of this error by cleaning the product and copying flag from debug to release in Linker flag. But its not working. Please tell me solution.

Comment: have you got the solution..I am also facing this problem

Comment: yes..but tell me the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: I have added the Analytics manualy not its working fine..thanks for your resposne :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with a bunch of others:

[image]

I went into the target's build settings and then found `Other Linker Flags`, I had a whole bunch of flags set. I removed them all except for `$(inherited) -ObjC` and then cleaned and built the project and it worked. Hopefully this will be helpful for someone else as well.